# Is "each" singular or plural?

Tags: word-choice, grammatical-number, verb-agreement

*You* goes with *are*. Does the presence of *each* change this?

> How satisfied **are** each of you with the time you've spent in your respective  universities.
>
> How satisfied **is** each of you with the time you've spent in your respective  universities

Comment: You may find this useful: https://www.grammar.com/each-singular-or-plural/                            Or this- https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/83127/each-of-them-is-or-each-of-them-are

Answer (score 1):

1. Under the traditional rule, the indefinite pronoun each is always singular and takes a singular verb.

Thus:
"Each of the golfers wants to win the PGA. Each of us wishes for success"

2. Pronouns Referring Back to “Each”

When the pronoun each is referred to by another pronoun, that other pronoun must appear in the singular.

Thus:
Each of the NFL players wants to increase his bonus. We must recognize that each has identified his or her own priorities.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is perfectly answered by the following reply by V.V. on the English language learners stack exchange to a very similar question; here are the pertinent parts:

"Each refers to every one of two or more people or things. [...] It is followed by the verb in the singular. [...]

Each of the answers **is** worth five points, but the answers **are** worth five points each."

This is the stack exchange question containing the original response by V.V.
https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/83127/each-of-them-is-or-each-of-them-are